# Dynamically set the Popup position/placement

Tags: silverlight, popup

The `Popup` control is left-aligned by default. Its left edge is aligned with the left edge of its parent.

What I would like to do is to have the control right-aligned so that its right edge is aligned with the right edge of its container.

I want this to be dynamic because I dynamically bind the data and I don't know how big the popup will be.

I tried playing with the `Opened`, `SizeChanged` and `Loaded` event to get the `Child`'s width and set it to the `HorizontalOffset` but there seems to be timing issues. Basically it works fine the first time the control is loaded and then never after (the `HorizontalOffset` is set to 0).

Is this a bug? Am I doing it the wrong way?

**EDIT** I got it working. It seems that there are timing issues. If I hook up the `Opened` event and set the `HorizontalOffset` asynchronously using the `Dispatcher`, then it works :(

```
    private static void OnPopupOpened(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = (Popup)sender;
        popup.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => popup.HorizontalOffset = -popup.ActualWidth);
    }
```

**EDIT 2** I now realise that I was doing something stupid. I wanted the `Popup` of the `ComboBox` to be right-aligned. I didn't see that it was reinitialized in the `ArrangePopup` private method call.
I tried inheriting from `ComboBox` to override the placement function but I must be doing something wrong because it still doesn't seem to work although I overrode the methods that call `ArrangePopup`

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I now realize that if I don't answer to my own question no one will be able to mark my work-around as an answer. So here's the full code. I implemented it as a PRISM behavior.

```
public static class PopupRightAlignBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InstanceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Instance", typeof(object), typeof(PopupRightAlignBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSetInstanceCallback));

    public static object GetInstance(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(InstanceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInstance(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InstanceProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSetInstanceCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = (Popup)d;
        popup.Opened -= OnPopupOpened;
        popup.Opened += OnPopupOpened;
    }

    private static void OnPopupOpened(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = (Popup)sender;
        popup.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => popup.HorizontalOffset = -popup.ActualWidth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use MS Expression Blend to generate the default template for a ComboBox. In the template you will find a Popup named Popup, change it's FlowDirection attribute to RightToLeft...

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

Note the ScrollViewer object inside the Popup will inherit the FlowDirection set so you have to explicitly set its FlowDirection to LeftToRight...

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
```

...else it will fill from RightToLeft and the scrollbar will be on the left hand side.