# Change the ComboBox Popup control to be right-aligned with the its parent

Tags: silverlight, combobox, popup, positioning

I'm trying to get a `ComboBox` to display its `Popup` right aligned rather than left-aligned as is the default.
I mean I want the right edge of the `Popup` to be aligned with the right edge of its parent.

I tried overriding the `ComboBox` class but that didn't quite work as the `Popup` HorizontalOffset seems to be reset somehow.
I thought that would be a fairly easy change but I can't find any resource talking about this issur.

Comment: At what point are you setting the Horizontal Offset?

Comment: I tried setting in the Opened and SizeChanged events. Then I tried overriding OnArrange but that didn't work either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set the Popup position/placement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362352/dynamically-set-the-popup-position-placement)

Answer (score 1):

In the ComboBox style change the flowDirection of the popup to RightToLeft.

```
<Style  TargetType="ComboBox">
     <Popup x:Name="Popup" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
</Style>
```

Comment: if i need the content in center horizontally??